# How to fix Column 'CourseNum' Does not belong to the table

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

I have a Database which has a table name **CourseOffered** that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiv8C.png)

The only column i want to select (request to be returned) is **Semester** and add it to a **dropdown** list. Here's my code in the Repository Class.

```
public List<CoursesOffered> GetSemester()
    {
        List<CoursesOffered> SemestersName = null;
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM CoursesOffered";
            DataTable dt = _idac.GetManyRowsCols(sql, null);
            SemestersName = DBList.ToList<CoursesOffered>(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return SemestersName;
    }
```

I'm calling **GetManyRowsCols()** from my **DataAccess Class** and I  have a **DBList** and **Entity Class** that looks like this.

```
class DBList
{
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt)
         where T : IEntity, new()
    {
        List<T> TList = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            T tp = new T();
            tp.SetFields(dr);
            TList.Add(tp);
        }
        return TList;
    }
}

 public class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public void SetFields(DataRow dr)
    {
        // use reflection to set the fields from DataRow          
        Type tp = this.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in tp.GetProperties())
        {
            if (null != pi && pi.CanWrite)
            {
                string nm = pi.PropertyType.Name.ToUpper();
                if (nm.IndexOf("ENTITY") >= 0)
                    // In LINQ to SQL Classes, last properties are links to other tables   
                    break;
                if (pi.PropertyType.Name.ToUpper() != "BINARY")
                    pi.SetValue(this, dr[pi.Name], null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i'm trying to add it to the Drop down List,

```
 private void CourseManagement_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<CoursesOffered> semesterList = _ibusinessSemester.GetSemester();
            cbCourseNumberDropDown.DataSource = semesterList;
            cbCourseNumberDropDown.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but i keep getting an error that says **Column 'CourseNum' Does not belong to the table**

Comment: can you show , where(line) are you getting this error? seems like some issue in mapping of CoursesOffered class and table fields.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the definition of the class CoursesOffered

Comment: Does method `GetSemester()` must return list of semester names? If it does, why do you map the result of the query with one column `SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM CoursesOffered` to the list of objects of type `CoursesOffered`? This leads to the error at the line `pi.SetValue(this, dr[pi.Name], null);`, because returned `DataTable` contains only one column `Semester`, and it does not contain column `CourseNum`.

Comment: @Sir Rufo,  the CoursesOffered class has fields and properties for CourseNum, Semester, MaxEnrollment.

Comment: How should i go about solving this issue @lliarTurdushev?

Comment: You can return a `List<string>` as a list of semester names, for example. Is such solution acceptable for you? For such solution you should implement a method that creates a `List<string>` (or generic list `List<T`>) from `DataTable` with a single column.

Comment: Well, DBList.ToList<CoursesOffered> tries to get data for all properties of CoursesOffered from the DataTable starting with the prop CourseNum, will not found in DataTable and throws the exception. Thats why

Comment: @lliarTurdushev I'm getting this error when i try to return **List<string>**..  **Type cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method DBList.ToList<T>(DataTable )  There is no implicit reference conversion from string to ....***

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to convert one column to list.

Since I don't have the code about `IEntity`, I can not test your code.

However, I make the following code to make it.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = DBList.ToList<string>(table, "Semeter").Distinct().ToList();// the code I have modified
            comboBox1.DataSource = list;
        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Course",typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Semeter", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("MaxEncrollment", typeof(int));
            table.Rows.Add("CPSC 410","Fall 2016",35);
            table.Rows.Add("CPSC 411", "Fall 2016", 30);
            table.Rows.Add("CPSC 440", "Fall 2016", 35);
            table.Rows.Add("Math301", "Fall 2016", 35);

        }
    }
    class DBList
    {
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt,string columnname)
        {
            List<T> TList = new List<T>();
            TList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<T>(columnname)).ToList();
            return TList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @J Jun, the code works,  but but i only wan the **Fall 2016** to appear once the Drop Down List

Comment: @Ricky, I have modified my code for appearing Fall 2016 once. You can check it.